# Find word after a match if word in list in python

Tags: python, string

How to find the word after a match, if word in list?
For example, I want to find the word after **match1** if this word is in list:

```
r = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
```

If found, then return the **word(i)**. If not, then return **Unknown**.

Toy example:

```
Text1 = "This is a match1 for example match1 random text match1 anotherword"
Text2 = "This is a match1 word1 example"
Text3 = "This is an example without word of interest"
```

I want to look the word after **match1** if this word is in list **r = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]**
Expected result:
For **Text1** I expect to get **Unknown**, for **Text2** **word1**, and for **Text3** **Unknown**.

I have managed so far to extract "word1" only if it's among the first two occurences, but if for example we have **Text4** (below) I can'textract it because I'm only going until the second time I see the match, and just keep going further and deeper with if-else statements I dont think its the way to go, because the **word1** can even not be present at all.

```
Text4 = "example match1 example match1 example match1 word1"

def get_labels(text):
    q = ["match1"] #Here the idea is to have several, but its the same logic
    r = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
    labels = []
    for i,item in enumerate(q):
        label = text[text.find(q[i])+len(q[i]):].split()[0]
        if label in r:
            labels.append(label)
        else:
            texto_temp = text[text.find(q[i])+len(q[i]):]
            label2 = texto_temp[texto_temp.find(q[i])+len(q[i]):].split()[0]
            labels.append(label2)
    return labels
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: A nested for loop? You can have a for loop inside a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) to find the matches.

*Code*

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re

def get_labels(text, match, words)
    tmp = re.findall(r'(?<={})\s+({})'.format(match, '|'.join(words)), text)

    return tmp if tmp else "Unknown"

Text1 = "This is a match1 for example match1 random text match1 anotherword"
Text2 = "This is a match1 word1 example"
Text3 = "This is an example without word of interest"
Text4 = "example match1 example match1 example match1 word1"

match = "match1"
words = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]

print(get_labels(Text1, match, words))
print(get_labels(Text2, match, words))
print(get_labels(Text3, match, words))
print(get_labels(Text4, match, words))
```

*Console Output*

```
Unknown
['word1']
Unknown
['word1']
```

Ask for more detail, if you are in need...

Comment: Thanks @sven-krüger , now how could I add the "unknown" if not found, like for Text1 and Text3? Thanks!

Comment: @juanman Feel free to accept my answer (green hook under the up-down-vote).

Comment: Thanks Sven, I got it working with this approach while iterating over a list of words to match.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly. This should work:

```
def get_labels(text):
    q = ['match1']
    r = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
    labels = []
    terms = text.split()
    for i, term in enumerate(terms[:-1]):
        if term in q and terms[i+1] in r:
            labels.append(terms[i+1])
    return labels if labels else 'Unknown'
```

Comment: Thanks @wjk2a1 but now how to print the "Unknown" or something for the matter, if not found? thanks!

Comment: If labels is empty you can return unknown: return labels if labels else 'Unknown'

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Positive Lookbehind (?<=match1\s)`

```
import re
pattern=r'(?<=match1\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+'

Text1 = "This is a match1 for example match1 random text match1 anotherword"
Text2 = "This is a match1 word1 example"
Text3 = "This is an example without word of interest"
Text4 = "example match1 example match1 example match1 word1"

r = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]

def word_checker(list_):
    data=re.findall(pattern,list_)
    list_data=[i for i in data if i in r]
    if list_data:
        return list_data[0]
    else:
        return 'Unknown'
```

output:

```
print(word_checker(Text1))
print(word_checker(Text2))
print(word_checker(Text3))
print(word_checker(Text4))
```

output:

```
Unknown
word1
Unknown
word1
```